# STPPaymentCardTextField for Android?

Tags: android, stripe-payments

In iOS I have used STPPaymentCardTextField to collect the card info.
Is there any similar cool view for android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a CardInputWidget in the Android SDK. It is not identical to the iOS view however : it displays the card numbers and expiration date from the beginning. So it takes more space. They say it needs a minimum width of 320dp.
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android#using-the-cardinputwidget

Answer (score 3):

Unlike iOS, Stripe's Android SDK does not provide such a text field. You have to create your own view. Stripe provides card validation for Android. So use that for validation.